# Тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

**Кто рано встает( )тот далеко от работы живет)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное предложение сложноподчинённое, поэтому здесь должна быть запятая. Если хотите использовать тире, предложение может выглядеть так: Далеко живёшь от работы - вставай пораньше:))